# Using custom classes in LinqScratchPad.aspx

Tags: content-search, indexing

### The problem

The default/sample code in the LinqScratchPad.aspx shows a `TryYourOwnClass` class. Sadly, this class is not used in any way in the sample.

The sample code looks like this:

```
namespace Test {
    class Program {
        public static IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> Main(string str)
        {
            using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
            {
                return context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Take(10).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}

[PredefinedQuery("_templatename", ComparisonType.Contains, "sample")]
public class TryYourOwnClass 
{
    [IndexField("_name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [IgnoreIndexFieldAttribute]
    public string DoNotMapMe { get; set;}
}
```

As you can see, `TryYourOwnClass` is defined, but is never used. I tried using `TryYourOwnClass` as the type for `GetQueryable`, but that won't run, as the `Main` method returns an `IEnumerable<SearchResultItem>`. And I cannot change the return type, because that will break the script as well.

### The question

So how do I use custom classes in the LinqScratchPad to query an index?

### Why am I trying to do that?

I'm working on a pretty constrained environment, where we are using a custom index with custom fields. Sadly, I cannot install any third-party tools like "Luke" or something like that. That's why I would like to use LinqScratchPad and a custom class to query the index using all the fields I want.

Comment: did you try to inherit your class from SearchResultItem class?

Comment: That totally did the trick. Thank you, @SitecoreClimber.
This should be updated in the sample code. :-D

Comment: I will transform my comment in an answer

Comment: How to add custom fields to the result here?

Comment: Just add a new property to the "TryYourOwnClass" class and add the corresponding IndexField-attribute. That should do the trick, @AnkitAgrawal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to inherits your custom class from **SearchResultItem** class if you want to return **`Queryable<SearchResultItem>`**

If you inherit from SearchResultItem, you will have all the goodies such as TemplateId, TemplateName, Name, CreatedBy, CreatedDate etc.
Your code will look like:

```
namespace Test {
    class Program {
        public static IEnumerable<SearchResultItem> Main(string str)
        {
            using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_master_index").CreateSearchContext())
            {
                return context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Take(10).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}

[PredefinedQuery("_templatename", ComparisonType.Contains, "sample")]
public class TryYourOwnClass : SearchResultItem
{
    [IndexField("_name")]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [IgnoreIndexFieldAttribute]
    public string DoNotMapMe { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. 
I believe the output is limited to `SearchResultItem`, right? So I can use my custom class (and fields) for the query, but cannot see the custom fields in the result, correct?

Comment: please decompile and have a look on this class : namespace Sitecore.Buckets.Client.sitecore.admin.LinqScratchPad

Comment: I found out, that it is not limited to the properties of `SearchResultItem`. The script outputs all custom fields as well. Pretty cool. I'm starting to love this admin page.